# Atmel STK500 and Atmel Studio

Tags: avr, programmer, atmel-studio

Is the [Atmel STK500](http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500070;c:100114#tc:description) worth using as a AVR programmer and Dev board? I am starting to get to into AVR programming with Atmel studio. I plan on purchasing the [AVRDragon](http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500053;c:100112#tc:description) and also looking into purchasing the Atmel STK500. This might be too broad of a question, but are their any benefits in using the Atmel STK500?

**Atmel STK500**

[image: Atmel STK500]

Comment: From reports, no. Stick to the Dragon.

Comment: Realize you don't need any of this - any ATmega-based Arduino with it's existing bootloader will do, completely unmodified.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - yes of course, but the Arduino does not have debugging and its also a pain when switching from prototyping on the arduino to flashing the AVR.

Comment: Did you try connecting to the ISP header?

Comment: No, never tried. Perhaps I should.

Comment: It's pretty antique (doesn't even has usb). I'm not even sure if it does debug-wire. Stick to the Dragon. Maybe buy a cheap USBASP on eBay, for spare/convenience. They work great for ISCP programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benefits of STK500? Sure:
- It has push buttons
- It has LEDs
- It has easy accessible connectors to any controller pin

Actually that's all. If you want/need to make use of this, buy both. Use the STK for "rapid prototyping" and the Dragon for debugging.
But if your budget allows it, have a look at the STK600 instead of 500. It's more expensive, but not so "old-fashioned", and it has much more features.